# How to restrict access to subdomains within a shared nginx server block?

Tags: nginx

I have a server block with a few different rules that catches its domain and all subdomains. I want `beta.mysite.com` to be private to my IP exclusively. However, I don't want to create a second server block as to avoid duplicating my rules. I could make a second server block and include the rules as a conf file, but I'd prefer not to.

Is there any way to conditionally limit access by IP based on the subdomain in this server block?

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.key;

        server_name mysite.com *.mysite.com;

        root /var/www/mysite.com/html;

        location / {
                include php.conf;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
                index index.php index.html;
        }

        location /public {
                autoindex on;
        }

        location /internal_data {
                internal;
        }

        location /library {
                internal;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need another `server` block. Whether you want it or not.

Comment: You can avoid duplication of rules by using the `include` function to write once and link to many